# MySQL sometimes not using the INDEX but sometimes it does

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, query-performance

Sometimes my query is not using the index, but some time it does. Can you guys explain me why is it happening?

This is the table structure.

```html
MariaDB [crm]> desc vtiger_project;
+------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| projectid              | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| projectname            | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| projecttype            | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| siteaddress            | varchar(500)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| state                  | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| district               | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| city                   | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| pincode                | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| phone                  | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| startdate              | date          | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| branch                 | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| customer               | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| dealer                 | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| contractor             | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| architect              | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| carpenter              | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| productcategory        | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| brand_preferred        | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| formal_spec_check      | varchar(3)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| formal_spec_details    | varchar(250)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| projectstatus          | varchar(25)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| project_reason_loosing | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| reason_loosing_deatils | varchar(250)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| reason_winning_deatils | varchar(250)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| adjustment             | decimal(25,8) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| exciseduty             | decimal(25,3) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| total                  | decimal(25,8) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| subtotal               | decimal(25,8) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| taxtype                | varchar(25)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| discount_percent       | decimal(25,3) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| discount_amount        | decimal(25,8) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| s_h_amount             | decimal(25,8) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| currency_id            | int(19)       | NO   |     | 1       |       |
| conversion_rate        | decimal(10,3) | NO   |     | 1.000   |       |
| actual_sale            | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| expected_sale_in_na    | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| primary_decision_maker | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

As you can see below output the first query does hitting the index, but the second one not, the only change i made on that query is **startdate** part.
What am i doing wrong?

```html
MariaDB [crm]> explain SELECT
    ->     COUNT(projectid)
    -> FROM
    ->     vtiger_project
    -> WHERE
    ->     82582 IN (customer , contractor, architect, carpenter)
    ->         AND projectstatus NOT IN ('Supplied' , 'Closed As Complete', 'Closed As Lost')
    ->         AND actual_sale IS NULL
    ->         AND startdate > NOW()
    -> ;
+------+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table          | type  | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                              |
+------+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | vtiger_project | range | startdate_idx | startdate_idx | 4       | NULL |  352 | Using index condition; Using where |
+------+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [crm]> explain SELECT
    ->     COUNT(projectid)
    -> FROM
    ->     vtiger_project
    -> WHERE
    ->     82582 IN (customer , contractor, architect, carpenter)
    ->         AND projectstatus NOT IN ('Supplied' , 'Closed As Complete', 'Closed As Lost')
    ->         AND actual_sale IS NULL
    ->         AND startdate < NOW()
    -> ;
+------+-------------+----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table          | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+------+-------------+----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | vtiger_project | ALL  | startdate_idx | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 15779 | Using where |
+------+-------------+----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
```

Comment: The query optimizer will do what it thinks it best for the query.  This can mean that sometimes an index won't be used if it doesn't help the query.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the rows column of the explain plan

in the first case  you have `352`

in the second `15779`

This suggests to query optimizer different strategies between the two queries.

*It could also be that you are executing the two queries in different servers or with other different conditions not evaulable by explain*

Comment: I am executing the query in same server, the only change is  startdate < NOW() In where clause,  if i make it  startdate > NOW() its using index..

Comment: then  is the number of row involved a.. as suggested  in my answer .. that  lead the query optimizer  to work in different way .. you can force the use of index adding force the use of specifi index  if you think the index work better  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html

Comment: @Salim *the only change is startdate < NOW()* ... If a significant number, perhaps a majority of the startdate values are < NOW(), **there is no point in using the index** for that particular query.  Beyond a certain percentage of the total number of rows in the table, a full scan is the more efficient strategy than using the index, because reading the other columns from the matching rows requires an extra read when using the index.  The scan avoids that when a large number of rows will match. It's not intuitive at first, but this behavior seems correct, to me, too.

Answer (score 0):

(sqlbot's comment answers the question.)

Further optimization *might* be available with this composite index:

```
INDEX(actual_sale, startdate)
```

But, that would probably work well only `actual_sale` is not `NULL` 'too often'.  Otherwise, a full table scan would be better, but the Optimizer might not figure that out.

Many of your columns seen to be excessively large.  Such excesses can lead to performance problems.